# Python - Principle Component Analysis error

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

I am in completing an Assignment for my Data Cleaning class where I must perform a PCA. You shouldn't need the data frame to help with this particular issue. I am a python noob. I've spent the last 3 hours trying to figure this out on my own with no success. The data frame as been cleaned and anomalies are sorted. I'm trying to create a PCA.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
from pylab import rcParams
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df_pcs = pd.read_csv('/Users/personal/Desktop/Data set/churn_raw_data.csv', usecols=['Churn','Age', 'Income', 'Outage_sec_perweek','Yearly_equip_failure', 'Tenure', 'MonthlyCharge'])
data_numeric = df_pcs[['Age', 'Income', 'Outage_sec_perweek','Yearly_equip_failure', 'Tenure', 'MonthlyCharge']]
data_normed = (df_pcs - df_pcs.mean()) / df_pcs.std()
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(data_normed)
data_pca = pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(data_normed),columns = data_numeric)
```

The error I'm getting: ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional

I'm not entirely sure how to make the index data 1 dimensional. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for what line do you get the error?

Comment: You probably need to replace `columns=data_numeric` with `columns=data_numeric.columns` given that `data_numeric` is a data frame.

Comment: columns=data_numeric.columns fixed the issue! wow, something so simple. lol thanks